# I was just expecting the char values to be printed.What is happening?

Tags: c++, char, cout

the output I was expecting was
a b c d
w x y z

is it something related to the order in which cout is processed,i mean left to right or right to left.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void dummy_func1() {
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char c = 'c';
    char d = 'd';
    cout<<&a<<" "<<&b<<" "<<&c<<" "<<&d<<endl;
}
char w = 'w';
char x = 'x';
char y = 'y';
char z = 'z';
void dummy_func2() {
    cout<<&w<<" "<<&x<<" "<<&y<<" "<<&z<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    dummy_func1();
    dummy_func2();
}
```

abcd bcd cd d

w xw yxw zyxw

Comment: Instead of `&a`, use `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit the `&` when passing char values to `cout`.

You are effectively passing a `char*`, and `cout` interprets that as a null-terminated string.

The fact that your program is not crashing is simply because of the way memory happens to be laid out by the C runtime.

The order of values in heap and stack memory is reversed, as you can see, but that is completely incidental, and only of interest if you want to dig into the internals of C/C++. :)

Comment: "You should omit the & when passing char values to cout. You are effectively passing char* and count interprets this as a string." actually i knew this ,but wanted to know why it was printing abcd when i printed &a. Thanks for the clarification. Can you please share a resource for this "Order of values in heap memory and stack memory is reversed, as you can see, but that is completely incidental, and only of interest if you want to dig into the internals of C/C++"

Comment: As far as I know in-memory variable layout is not mandated by the standard unless you put your variables in a struct. The reversed order stems from the fact that static data is preallocated, and the stack grows backwards.

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj

https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/aviv/classes/ic221/s16/lec/08/lec.html